# Como eu faria uma div sem refresh

Tags: javascript

Minha dúvida é o seguinte, estou "desenvolvendo" uma web rádio, e meu problema é o seguinte, quando o usuário navega no site ele da refresh na página e automaticamente o player para de tocar, então minha dúvida é essa, como eu faria pra essa `div` do player não atualizar com a navegação no site ?

```
<div id="player" class="align_left">
        <div class="align overflow">    
            <div class="botao align_left">
                <ul>
                    <li><button><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" title="Play"></i></button></li>
                    <li><button><i class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true" title="Pause"></i></button></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <audio src="http://stm4.srvstm.com:19404/;" class="player align_left" autoplay="autoplay"></audio></div>
```

oque eu tenho é isso, e uma pequena estização de `CSS`, alguém poderia dar um exemplo de como fazer isso ?

Comment: Acho que nesse caso vc pode fazer um LocalStorage com javascript pra logo depois do refresh o áudio voltar de onde parou

Comment: não teria como fazer sem atualizar nada? sem parar o audio ?

Comment: @hugocsl rádios online já voltam de onde pararam, o que acho que ele quer é uma página não mude, e dentro dessa mesma tudo mude para a nova página... menos a tag audio que contém a URL STREAM.


Eu já vi vários sistemas desse tipo (Usam AJAX), vou ver a melhor solução e postar a resposta aqui.

Comment: Ok, é isso mesmo que eu preciso RpgBoss

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso de duas formas. Com [**iframe**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) ou [**Pjax** = PushState And Ajax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax).

#### Iframe

O [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) é basicamente representa um contexto de navegação. Ele incorpora uma página HTML e dessa forma permite que você possa ter várias páginas em uma só.

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira: https://gist.github.com/valdeir2000/41356d2e412324516c0d6064ee9ec1ec

---

#### pJax

O [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) funciona como uma requisição feita em Ajax. O código envia um pedido para `algum_pagina.php`, essa página é retornada e tratada.

Você só precisa definir um "container" idêntico para todas as páginas, dessa forma tudo que tiver dentro desse "container", será retornado e exibido na tela sem atualiza-la.

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira: https://gist.github.com/valdeir2000/3b0fe820cd7e8ff655e586847e7bdd2a

---

Estou montando um site que segue esse padrão. Segue [**Demonstração**](http://www.rickcds.com)

Comment: nenhum funcionou, não teria um jeito com js ?

Comment: @Bruno *PJAX* é com JavaScript. Você chegou a baixar algum dos exemplos e testar?

Comment: sim, porém deu refresh

Comment: No último exemplo só dá refresh no link `Acessar nova página COM atualização`. Você está testando em um servidor Nginx ou Apache?

Comment: Apache, ele da refresh nos dois exemplos