# Trocar conteúdo de uma div por um arquivo html

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Estou fazendo um portfólio simples que não vai precisar de nenhum Framework como angular ou react, o que eu gostaria e fazer algo para que eu pudesse criar os arquivos html separados e um principal apenas trocando o conteúdo da pagina com JavaScript. Algo assim, meu index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>titulo principal que vai estar em todas as paginas</h1>
  <div>
    div onde quero ficar alterando meus arquivos
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Um outro arquivo qualquer:

```
<div>subtitulo da pagina</div>
```

Outro arquivo html

```
<div>outro subtitulo</div>
```

Quero fazer com que esses arquivos sejam colocados dentro do meu html principal, não me preocupo de importar todos os css e javascript diretamente no meu arquivo principal já que vai ser algo muito leve, mas gostaria muito de fazer esse sistema de troca de arquivos.

Comment: Você quer fazer uma `one page application` isso normalmente se faz com Ajax. Seria melhor você estudar o Ajax do que ficar pedindo opnião, voce pode dar uma olhada: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) ou [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) MDN é mais recomendado porque é mais atualizado, já o W3Schools é mais prático, vai direto ao assunto, porém um pouco desatualizado.

Comment: Não tinha nem ideia de por onde começar, vou estudar Ajax e ver se consigo fazer. Obrigado.

Comment: Acho que isso pode ajuda-lo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/276631/99718

Answer (score 1):

A resposta que o Hugo citou acima, é a forma mais semântica de fazer isso.

Só para conhecimento, uma breve explicação: Por exemplo, no `C#` usamos o `<!--#include file=".caminho_do_arquivo" -->` para incluir diferentes partes de arquivos em nossa aplicação.

**Qual a vantagem dessa utilização?**

Suponhamos que temos uma aplicação com diversas páginas diferentes, normalmente o que irá mudar nessas páginas será apenas o conteúdo, componentes como `menu` e `rodapé` dificilmente serão alterados. Ao invés de criarmos esses componentes em todas as páginas, podemos criar arquivos separados para cada um deles, e no final fazer a chamada desses arquivos em seu documento.

**Exemplo:**

Temos os arquivos `index.aspx`, `maisVisitados.aspx` e `sobreNos.aspx`, então criamos os arquivos que serão reutilizados nessas páginas `menu.asp` e `rodape.asp` e fazemos a chamada deles em cada um desses arquivos: `<div> <!--#include file="menu.asp" --> </div> //aqui vai o menu` e `<div> <!--#include file="rodape.asp" --> </div> //aqui vai o rodapé`.

No final, a página `index.aspx` por exemplo, se parecerá com isso:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
  <div> <!--#include file="menu.asp" --> </div> 
  <main> 
    conteúdo principal do site
  </main>
  <div> <!--#include file="rodape.asp" --> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Concluindo**

No fundo, para obtermos a página final (`index.aspx`), temos que juntar vários outros arquivos para chegar no resultado final, basta pensar na estrutura de sua página como se fosse peças de lego.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso com PHP usando `<?php include 'seuarquivo.html';?>`

A sua página que vai receber esses `includes` precisa ser um `.PHP`, porém os arquivos que vc vai chamar pelo `include` podem ser HTMLs simples. *(se vc quiser pode usar o include com outras extensões, só não é possível fazer include de links tipo "https://pt.stackoverflow.com/" a não ser que vc use um "[empacotadores de inclusão de URL](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include)")*

**Veja o Exemplo:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>titulo principal que vai estar em todas as paginas</h1>
  <div>
    <?php include 'item1.html';?> <!-- seu conteúdo externo -->
  </div>
  <div>
    <?php include 'item2.html';?> <!-- seu conteúdo externo -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Os arquivos .HTML que vc vai chamar nos includes não precisam de `<!DOCTYPE html>` `<html>` `<head>` ou `<body>` vc pode começar direto pela `<nav>` `<header>`  `<section>` ou `<div>` por exemplo. Então dentro do seu `item1.html` só precisaria disso por exemplo:

```
<div>
  <h2>titulo do item1</h2>
  <p>Conteúdo do item1 por exemplo</p>
</div>
```

**OBS:** Para testar os arquivos `.PHP` vc precisa rodar um servidor local tipo Wamp ou Xamp, pois o browser não consegue interpretar o PHP sozinho, tem que estar no Local Server ou em algum FTP

***Manual PHP do Include:*** http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php

Comment: Olá Downvoter, eu ficaria feliz se vc puder contribuir comentando o que está errado e onde eu poderia melhorar.